# Python interpreter crashes on execution

Tags: macos, crash, python, symlink

having bought my first macbook I am not very experienced in debugging the libraries and a bit at a loss. Upon execution of my python script the following error report shows up:

> Process:               Python [356] Path:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   Identifier:            Python Version:               2.7.10 (2.7.10)
>   Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        bash
>   [262] Responsible:           Terminal [225] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2015-09-25 12:53:24.544 +0200 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   2262FF9F-1D12-77B0-74D3-208AC3A26542
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 27 seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information: abort() called
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8b956286 **pthread_kill +
>   10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8b9c49b3 abort +
>   129 2   org.python.python                 0x000000010b6fe2a3
>   Py_FatalError + 49 3   org.python.python
>
>   0x000000010b6fd785 PyThreadState_Get + 28 4   org.python.python
>
>   0x000000010b6fa522 Py_InitModule4_64 + 62 5   libboost_python.dylib
>
>   0x000000010b5e1e24 boost::python::detail::init_module(char const*,
>   void (*)()) + 36 6   org.python.python
>
>   0x00000001000deba1 _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 177 7
>
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000dd28b import_submodule
>   + 315 8   org.python.python                 0x00000001000dd73a load_next + 234 9   org.python.python
>
>   0x00000001000dda30 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 336 10 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000bafe3
>   builtin___import** + 131 11  org.python.python
>   0x000000010000c612 PyObject_Call + 98 12  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000bc1c7 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87 13 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000c0432
>   PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12210 14  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000c58e3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115 15  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000c5a06 PyEval_EvalCode + 54 16  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000da0a0 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 208 17 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000db2a2
>   load_source_module + 626 18  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000dd28b import_submodule + 315 19  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000dd73a load_next + 234 20  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000dda30 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 336 21 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000bafe3
>   builtin___import__ + 131 22  org.python.python
>   0x000000010000c612 PyObject_Call + 98 23  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000bc1c7 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87 24 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000c0432
>   PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12210 25  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000c58e3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115 26  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000c5a06 PyEval_EvalCode + 54 27  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000da0a0 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 208 28 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000db2a2
>   load_source_module + 626 29  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000dd28b import_submodule + 315 30  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000dd7c1 load_next + 369 31  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000dda30 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 336 32 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000bafe3
>   builtin___import__ + 131 33  org.python.python
>   0x000000010000c612 PyObject_Call + 98 34  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000bc1c7 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87 35 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000c0432
>   PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12210 36  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000c58e3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115 37  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000c5a06 PyEval_EvalCode + 54 38  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000da0a0 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 208 39 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000db2a2
>   load_source_module + 626 40  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000dd28b import_submodule + 315 41  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000dd73a load_next + 234 42  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000dda7c PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 412 43 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000bafe3
>   builtin___import__ + 131 44  org.python.python
>   0x000000010000c612 PyObject_Call + 98 45  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000bc1c7 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87 46 
>   org.python.python                 0x00000001000c0432
>   PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12210 47  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000c58e3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115 48  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000c5a06 PyEval_EvalCode + 54 49  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000ea41e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174 50  org.python.python
>   0x00000001000ea6ba PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458 51  org.python.python
>   0x000000010010187d Py_Main + 3101 52  org.python.python
>   0x0000000100000f14 0x100000000 + 3860

So .... how do I read this? What is broken, wrongfully linked or otherwise? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How did you install python as that path is not the standard OS X one

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer mate. Let us say there was a lot of experimentation. I installed quite a few libraries, some of them rather voluminous and with their own python distributions. May I ask how you what the correct path is and how i might be able to change that?

Comment: The issue is if done correctly then the old path is still there. From your comment the best way would be reinstall the OS from scratch. Try using /usr/bin/python to start the python this should be the OS X supplied one, if it is not then you have to reinstall OS X

Comment: Hey Mark, that did something (now simple custom imports cloud my day). So, do I assume correctly that a non system interpreter is called by "python"? In this case I should be able to simply change the reference, right?

Comment: Look at your path to fix that

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to software debugging. That topic is too broad to convey in a short answer here, but hopefully some context and guidelines will help.

1. Your Python program itself crashed - so you don't easily know what call or sequence of calls caused the error from the container crashing.
2. Gather details like what version of Python is running, what version of each library.
3. Try enabling debug flags for the libraries or run the python script in a python debugger so you can know where the crash ocurrs.

Once or have that level of detail, you'll start to isolate the issue by reducing the complexity of the code by removing all that's necessary to either stop crash or have a minimal example of the crashing behavior (say 10 lines of Python plus whatever data setup is needed) and ask about that in Stack Overflow.